# Почему не получается делать условие mysql сразу из двух ячеек?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

Если искать в столбце `meta_value` по ячейке `biolw`, то в результате получаем 2 значении `post_id`, `137` и `139` (смотрите второй столбец в картинке).
Код для этого выглядит так (в `PDO`):

```
$respq = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value IN ('biolw')");

foreach($respq as $respqp){   
echo $rowxn = $respqp["post_id"]."<br>";
}
```

Но если попытаться отделить их таким образом:

```
$respq = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value IN ('biolw','month')");

foreach($respq as $respqp){   
echo $rowxn = $respqp["post_id"]."<br>";
}
```

то выводится много значений `post_id` (почти все). Как делать правильно, чтобы вывелся только `post_id` с номером 139 (как и должен)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value IN ('biolw','month')
group by post_id
having count(distinct meta_value)=2
```